# sorting based on value

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I need to sort the words based on the frequency count as achieved below.

splitting words after cleaning for the stop words:

```
words=Counter([item for sublist in m.split('\W+') for item in word_tokenize(sublist)])
```

Frequency Count:

```
wordsFreq=['%s: %d' %(x, words[x]) for x in words]
```

output:

```
["limited: 1", "desirable: 1", "advices: 1","new: 8", "net: 5", "increasing: 2",......]

print type(wordsFreq)
```

output

```
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: What's your question? This appears to just be a statement of what you've written.

Comment: Carcigenicate  - I need to sort the output list based on the frequency count. for an instance limited:1, desirable:1, advices:1, increasing:2, new:5, new: 8....

Comment: Give this a good read over: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting. `sort` has an optional parameter that can allow you to choose what elements are sorted by. You probably won't want them to be made into strings before sorting though. That'll complicate things.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Carcigenicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert your data into a dictionary with words as keys and frequencies as values:

```
import operator

in_lst = ["limited: 1", "desirable: 1", "advices: 1",
             "new: 8", "net: 5", "increasing: 2"]

freq_dict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [i.split(": ") for i in in_lst]}

sorted_lst = sorted(freq_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

out_lst = [": ".join(i) for i in sorted_lst]
```

This program then orders the items based on the value in the dictionary. `sorted_lst` is a list of tuples that are then converted to a list of original strings, sorted by their frequency in increasing order.

Another solution would be to use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module.

Comment: this is a great illustration, atru. Thank you